# Complex integral on real axis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I need to show $\int_m^\infty{\sqrt{x^2-m^2}e^{-ixt}dx} \sim_{t \to \infty} e^{-imt}$. I tried to use the fact that the integral has branch points at $\pm m$, but I didn't get anything. Then I tried to do the substitution $z=m+x$ and the integral becomes $e^{-imt}\int_0^\infty\sqrt{z^2+2mz}e^{-izt}dz$. But I am not sure how to go from here. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Is $i=\sqrt{-1}$?  If so, I don't think it converges.

Comment: As commented, the integral looks suspicious, but also the fact that as $\;t\to\infty\;$ , the left side is asymptotically equivalent to the right side, $\;e^{-imt}\;$ , which **still** depends on $\;t\;$ ...